# Clamped B-spline curves

Tags: curves, spline

This is not a question about research , i am trying to create B-Spline curves but i don't understand how can i generate a clamped B-spline?More precisely the knots are fixed($m = n + p + 1$) , how can i make first 4 and last 4 knots idenctical, as an example shown below? Picture is in attachment  and source : http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-curve.html [image]

Answer (score 2):

The knot vector is part of the b-spline definition. So, just make the first 4 knots 0.0 and the last 4 knots 1.0 and the resulting cubic b-spline curve will be clamped.

Comment: yes i calculated values and found that this also changes the shape of the curve! is this correct?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "this also changes the shape of the curve". You have degree, knot vector and control points that fully defines a B-spline curve. What "shape of the curve" are you comparing against?